# Shared set of .csproj(s) to include/add/import into multiple .sln(s)

Tags: visual-studio

I have multiple projects setup to include project references they have in common, via an `<import>` in their `.csproj`.
I've even found out how to semi-automate that with `Directory.Build.props`.

Now the issue is, each of these projects I have setup to share the same imports, actually has their own solution so they can be worked on individually.
And currently, I have to manually setup them all to include the commonly referenced projects (sure, they build without it in the solution, but I ***want*** them in it).

Is there any syntax at all within a .sln file for doing this, like an import, or i guess .. anything?

Comment: That's not possible.